# Writing to file from subprocess doesn't always work, unless I include file.write()

Tags: python, python-2.7, io, subprocess

My code looks like this:

```
for i in range(5):
    with open(file_path, 'a') as some_file:
        subprocess.Popen("command_to_run", stdout=some_file, stderr=subprocess.stdout).wait()
```

When I run this, some_file only contains the output of 'command_to_run' once. I'm pretty sure it's only the final iteration of the loop.

If i modify the code to looks like this:

```
for i in range(5):
    with open(file_path, 'a') as some_file:
        some_file.writelines("iteration: " + str(i))
        subprocess.Popen("command_to_run", stdout=some_file, stderr=subprocess.stdout).wait()
        some_file.writelines("iteration: " + str(i))
```

then suddenly everything works! I can't figure out why though. I'm pretty unfamiliar with files/subprocesses, so maybe it's something obvious, but I haven't been able to find anything online. Any ideas?

Comment: Your command is certainly able to influence this -- if it does a `seek(0)` when stdout isn't a TTY, it'll go back and overwrite prior contents. But then, that would generally happen just as much with the other write as without it.

Comment: Can you generate a [mcve] -- that is, the smallest possible code someone else can run to see the same problem? Right now this needs a `command_to_run` nobody but you has seen.

Comment: ...btw, I might consider putting the `with open(file_path, 'a') as some_file` on the *outside*, and the `for i in range(5)` within it. No point to re-opening the output file over and over when you could just have one handle and reuse it.

Comment: The command is pretty specific to some software/hardware i'm using, and i'm not sure how to repo it otherwise :(

Comment: If it doesn't reproduce with any command other than the one you're using (ie. you can't reproduce it with `Popen(['printf', r'%s\n', 'test output'], stdout=some_file, stderr=subprocess.stdout)`), that's a useful datapoint in and of itself.